# Can Reader Accounts connect to 3rd party BI tool (ex Tableau)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I know Snowflake Reader Accounts let users query  databases shared with them but can they connect the reader account to a 3rd party BI or Data Analysis tool like Tableau as you can with a Full Account.

Comment: A read only account would be the preferred connection method for a reporting-only tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a reader account is a "full account" that only reads, thus they cannot create tables etc. But most BI tools only read.

Now maybe there is a more subtle question that you mean, which is some tooling might understand their target DB and user things like temp tables to do work, which a reader account does not allow, and thus you are possibly really asking.

> Can someone confirm Tableau works against a reader account?

Which I cannot directly answer, we have customers that use our reader accounts, but I have not seen specific see Tableau usage.